# are the crosses literally forbidden in islam or is it what symbolises them?

Tags: halal-haram

I know crosses are forbbiden, but what about crosses used in math like the additional sign "+" & multiplication sign "x"? Or is it what Symbolises them that is forbbiden?

Al-Bukhaari narrated in his Saheeh from ‘Aa’ishah (may Allaah be pleased with her) that the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) would never leave anything in his house on which there were any crosses without erasing them or – according to another report –cutting them out.

Answer (score 1):

Only the crosses which refers to *polytheism* is **forbidden**, but any other crosses (which don't have such meaning) are **allowed**, and it's being used through the history of **Islam** in many different situations ..

Comment: What about the evil eye, people hang at houses or use it in keychains